# Notifications not shown after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: notification

After upgrading to 22.04 recently, I noticed that I don't see notifications anymore. They are displayed in the list of notifications, but the "popup" never appears as they arrive.

Do Not Disturb mode is deactivated.

[image: notify-send executed, no popup]

[image: all previous notifications displayed in list]

Comment: Strange I do not have any notifications in the calendar. Do not disturb is turned off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved itself after multiple (?) reboots. I think there was a Google Chrome update too in the meantime.